If statement with multiple conditions in pandas
I have the below df
|  Col A   |    Col B
-----------------------
| Nan      |    3144
| Nan      |    3145
| 123      |    3246
| Nan      |    Nan

I would like to add a new column C with the following logic:
if Col A is null and Col B is populated with some data, then A
else if Col A and Col B has some data or if both columns have nulls then B.
So the result should look like this.
|  Col A   |    Col B    |    Col C
-------------------------------------
| Nan      |    3144     |    A
| Nan      |    3145     |    A
| 123      |    3246     |    B
| Nan      |    Nan      |    B

how do I get this? fairly new to Python

what should be output if Col A has non-null and Col B has null value?

The logic for what Col C should contain is not complete, the case where Col A contains data and Col B is Nan is missing. In either case, numpy.where() can be used:
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col A': [np.nan, np.nan, 123, np.nan, 123],
    'Col B': [3144, 3145, 3246, np.nan, np.nan]
})

Assuming Col C should contain either A or B, there are two answers:

Col C should contain 'A' when Col A contains data and Col B contains Nan:

df['Col C'] = np.where(df['Col A'].isna().eq(df['Col B'].isna()), 'B', 'A')


Col C should contain 'B' when Col A contains data and Col B contains Nan:

df['Col C'] = np.where((df['Col A'].isna()) & (~df['Col B'].isna()), 'A', 'B')


Use a simple condition where we check if the values are NaN or not, and after that we use np.where with the condition "Col A is equal to Col B". If the condition is True, returns B, else 'A'
m = df.isna()
df['Col C'] = np.where(m['Col A'].eq(m['Col B']), 'B', 'A')

End result:
 Col A  Col B Col C
   NaN 3144.0     A
   NaN 3145.0     A
 123.0 3246.0     B
   NaN    NaN     B


you can use np.where to check the values in both columns and then assign the result to a new column :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col A': [np.nan, np.nan, 123, np.nan],
    'Col B': [3144, 3145, 3246, np.nan]
})

df['Col C'] = np.where(df['Col A'].isna() & ~df['Col B'].isna(), 'A', 'B')

print(df)
  Col A   Col B Col C
0    NaN  3144.0     A
1    NaN  3145.0     A
2  123.0  3246.0     B
3    NaN     NaN     B

